# Adding Fragments Dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am thoroughly confused.  According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
and [this](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/programmatically-working-with-android-fragments/) and numerous other sources, both on SO and elsewhere, I should be able to do the following:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    MainRightFragment mrf = new MainRightFragment();
    RecommendedFragment rf = new RecommendedFragment();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.main_search_boxes, mrf, "fragmentright");
    ft.add(R.id.main_left_side, rf, "fragmentreccomend");
}
```

}

The R.id references point to FrameLayout objects in my .xml file.  Why am I still getting the "*The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, RecommendedFragment, String)*" error message?

Comment: are you sure RecommendedFragment extends fragment? 
does it work for one frag only? did u try commiting between both?

Answer (score 8):

Your `MainScreenActivity` should extends `FragmentActivity` and not just `Activity`.
Also, don't forget to call `ft.commit();`

Answer (score 3):

To add fragments at Runtime you need to extends your main activity from: **android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity**

And you need to use the classes FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction from  **android.support.v4.app** package, instead of android.app.

Also, when you get the FragmentManager use the method getSupportFragmentManager(). See the code below:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

FragmentTop fragTop = new FragmentTop();
FragmentLeft fragLeft = new FragmentLeft();

FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

ft.add(R.id.fragTop, fragTop);
ft.add(R.id.fragLeft, fragLeft);

ft.commit();
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a capitulation than an answer, but I was able to get what I wanted using FragmentActivity/support.v4.app.  I still don't understand why the references I cited above seem to say that it is possible to use the .add(...) function with the modern API.
Both harsha.cs and Damien point to FragmentActivity, so until someone explains why it is necessary to use the backwards compatibility API, I will give both points, and hold off on checking an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(FragmentA.this.getParent().getID(), mNewFragment,"your frame name");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Is FragmentA in your example a class or an instance?  In neither case can I get your code to compile :(

Comment: @AharonManne: in the code above replace `mNewFragment` with your mrf `Fragment` which you initiated using `MainRightFragment mrf = new MainRightFragment();`

Comment: @AharonManne: FragmentA is the parent fragment. BTW please extend your class by `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`

Comment: FragmentActivity is for android.support.v4.app.  According to [this training document](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) the support library is for API 10 and below, and I am not targeting those devices. My question was about the first parameter in ft.add, which requires a layout id.